# scroll-based image sequences animation more smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css, smooth-scrolling, gsap

I want a Scroll-Based Animation with image sequences like this:

https://www.wayoutintl.com/

when visit above link ,see section-3 when we scroll down, beach image move from day to night. This animation seems scroll smoothly. my animation scroll smoothly on local and when i put same code on server,sequences images choppy on scroll. not smoothly work on scroll. So what should i do now ? Please help me ..... thanks in advance.... below is my code....

```js
// define images
            var images = [
                "imgs/0001/0001-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0002-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0003-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0004-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0005-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0006-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0007-compress2.jpg",
                "imgs/0001/0008-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0009-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0010-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0011-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0012-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0013-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0014-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0015-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0016-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0017-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0018-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0019-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0020-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0021-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0022-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0023-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0024-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0025-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0026-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0027-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0028-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0029-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0030-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0031-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0032-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0033-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0034-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0035-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0036-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0037-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0038-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0039-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0040-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0041-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0042-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0043-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0044-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0045-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0046-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0047-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0048-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0049-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0050-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0051-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0052-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0053-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0054-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0055-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0056-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0057-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0058-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0059-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0060-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0061-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0062-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0063-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0064-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0065-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0066-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0067-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0068-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0069-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0070-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0071-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0072-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0073-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0074-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0075-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0076-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0077-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0078-compress2.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0079-compress3.jpg",
               "imgs/0001/0080-compress3.jpg"

            ];

            // TweenMax can tween any property of any object. We use this object to cycle through the array
            var obj = {curImg: 0};

            // create tween
            var tween = TweenMax.to(obj, 0.5,
              {
                curImg: images.length - 1,  // animate propery curImg to number of images
                roundProps: "curImg",       // only integers so it can be used as an array index
                repeat: 0,                 // repeat 3 times
                immediateRender: true,      // load first image automatically
                ease: Linear.easeNone,      // show every image the same amount of time
                onUpdate: function () {
                  $("#myimg").attr("src", images[obj.curImg]); // set the image source
                }
              }
            );

            // init controller
            var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

            // build scene
            var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger", duration: 800})
                    .setTween(tween)
                    .addTo(controller);
```

```html
<div class="image-seq">
    <section class="demo">
    <div class="spacer s0" id="trigger"></div>
    <div id="imagesequence">
      <img id="myimg" class="lazy"/><br>    
    </div>
  </section>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/as.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.7/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why use ScrollMagic? [ScrollTrigger](http://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) is way better, just sayin'. Plus [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3/) is way better than GSAP 1 like you're using. And there are [demos](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/VweybzG) [doing this sort of thing](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24443-sprite-animation-sequence-with-new-scrolltrigger/?tab=comments#comment-116388).

Comment: what the solution of this problem ? can you inform me ?

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll, you are queuing up the images (maybe many) to be loaded on the next requestAnimationFrame which is why it works ok on local, but not when on a server.
Some of the images are fairly large (the stadium ones are around 150kB each, and you seem to have over 300 of them). The total page size is around 65MB.

Things to try:
Preload the images before initializing the scroller.
Reduce the amount of images and maybe their size.
Try using webP images to reduce their size.
Use vanilla JS to set the image source instead of jQuery.
Use the browser dev tools (network and performance tabs) to check where you bottlenecks are. It might be helpful to set the throttling to 3g so you can test performance on your local version.